# How can I cancel all the current communication from particular IP in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ufw

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 firewall. I want to deny any IP on runtime. I am using "ufw deny from IP". It's working for future connections. But it is not cancelling the existing connections like ssh.

How can I cancel all the current communication from particular IP?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The best option I've found is to use `tcpkill`.  When I installed it, it was part of the `dsniff` package, so I had to install that first. 
Then, you would use it like this :

```
$ sudo tcpkill ip host 20.129.11.86 and port 22
tcpkill: listening on eth0 [ip host 20.129.11.86 and port 22]
10.206.22.202:42532 > 20.129.11.86:22: R 1785992582:1785992582(0) win 0
10.206.22.202:42532 > 20.129.11.86:22: R 1785992732:1785992732(0) win 0
10.206.22.202:42532 > 20.129.11.86:22: R 1785993032:1785993032(0) win 0
20.129.11.86:22 > 10.206.22.202:42532: R 4065251855:4065251855(0) win 0
20.129.11.86:22 > 10.206.22.202:42532: R 4065301087:4065301087(0) win 0
20.129.11.86:22 > 10.206.22.202:42532: R 4065399551:4065399551(0) win 0
```

As soon tcpkill detects matching traffic, it will terminate the connection.

To see where else the IP is hitting your system, you can use `netstat -aunt` and grep for the IP address. E.g.,

```
$ netstat -aunt | egrep 115.125.
tcp        0      0 10.20.22.25:56156     115.125.225.67:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.20.22.25:42360     115.125.225.1:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.20.22.25:35210     115.125.225.64:80        ESTABLISHED
```

Create further ufw rules if necessary.

Is restarting ssh an option?

You can use `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd stop` then `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd start`, or use the service mechanism:

```
$ sudo service ssh stop
ssh stop/waiting
$ sudo service ssh start
ssh start/running, process 4427
```

You could drop the interface temporarily, if that's an option.

There's an app called 'cutter' that should work, taking the IP address and port as arguments.  However, I wasn't able to get the package to install correctly from

`$ sudo apt-get install cutter`

It's supposed to work something like this (assuming standard port 22 for ssh):

`$ cutter 10.10.10.10 22`

You might also check out something like the `denyhosts` package.

Comment: I tried sudo /etc/init.d/sshd stop but it is not working.. existing ssh connection is still alive..

Comment: I added some more options.  tcpkill worked best in my tests.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but you can try with `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --source 192.168.1.1 -j REJECT
```

Or if you want to be pedantic

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --source 192.168.1.1 REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Check this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that, as written, that command is limited to connections to port 22 (which is usually the port on which an SSH server listens). This command could be generalized to block all traffic from that IP address.

Comment: You should use REJECT rather then DROP See - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject

Comment: There are 2 problems with this answer. First you did not describe how to use and save iptables configuarationg and the other problem is that it is not such a good idea to mix iptables and UFW.

Comment: Even "ufw reject from IP" is not working.. the existing ssh and connections are still connected

Comment: I tried "cutter IP", but it is also not working